# Checking missing combination of co-ordinates in a 4D plot and adding dummy values for the missing combination

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, scatter

I have a 4D plot plotted using matplotlib with the 4th dimension being color.

Lets assume the range of all the 3 axes to be 0 to 5. Array for plot looks something like this - [0,1,2,50],[1,2,3,40],[5,5,5,80]. So I will see 3 points on co-ordinates [0,1,2],[1,2,3],[5,5,5] in the graph when plotted (assuming a scatter plot).

My question is - is there any way to check the combinations of co-ordinates on the plot which do not have any points. In the above case, for example, there are no points on co-ordinates [1,2,4],[1,2,5],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[4,1,2],[5,3,1] and so on. I can individually check if there is an element (between 0 and 5) which is not covered in a particular axis (using 'is in'). But how to get the missing combination of co-ordinates and then plot it in the graph with some dummy value ? Any leads or solution would be appreciated.

```
#create an empty list
list1 = []

#append elements to the list
list1.append([0,1,2,50])
list1.append([1,2,3,40])
list1.append([5,5,5,80])
```

## using the scatter plot

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['green', 'yellow', 'red']) 


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
ax.set_zlim(0,5)

#convert list into array for slicing 
array1 = np.array(list1)
ax.scatter(array1[:,0],array1[:,1],array1[:,2],c=array1[:,3], cmap = cmap)
plt.show()
```

for the above i need to add zeroes to remaining co-ordinates. 
When i plot, the co-ordinates (0,1,2) gets a color corresponding to 50, (1,2,3) gets a color corresponding to 40 and similarly for co-ordinates (5,5,5). So the remaining co-ordinates should be appended with zeroes. Like (1,4,1,0), (1,3,5,0), (2,4,1,0) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle this problem. Instead of checking on where there are not coordinates available, I'd initialize a matrix with the dummy value and set all available to the value they are supposed to have. It looks like this:

```
myData = [[0,1,2,50], [1,2,3,40], [5,5,5,80]]
fullMatrix = np.empty(shape=(6,6,6), dtype=np.int8) # 0 to 5 in each dimension
fullMatrix.fill(-1) # -1 is an example for the dummy value

for i in myData:
        fullMatrix[i[0],i[1],i[2]] = i[3]
```

Comment: Hey the idea is good. but i am using append method for the fullMatrix later in my code. if i use your method, I am getting the below error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: In numpy you cannot "append" things to a matrix. You need to `stack`. You need to tell numpy in which dimension you want to append. You could edit your question and add example code of what you are trying to append and I can have a look at it if you want. Or you can of course convert the matrix back to a list but that would be kind of weird.

Comment: What does that mean, you need to add zeros? Is zero your "no data value"? You said you need to append something, but it's unclear what you append and where. Please give us example data ...

Comment: Have edited the Original Post. The final part is more clear now.